# How to upload pdf and pptx files to google docs via the gdata python client?

Tags: python, google-docs, gdata, gdata-python-client

I'm using the gdata python client for the google docs api for a project. I use oauth authentication and all the dance, and have successfully uploaded .doc, .xls and every file type in [Their FAQ](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/documents/faq.html#WhatKindOfFilesCanIUpload). 
**but** I cannot seem to upload pdf files, even though is right there, listed on the supported filetypes. I tried with the latest version of gdata (released last week) to no avail. Also, I'd like to be able to upload .pptx files, though I realize that that extension is not supported.

Has anybody out there ***succesfully uploaded a pdf file*** to google docs via their gdata python client?

Comment: I've never done this kind of thing, but an error message or some detail like that would be helpful. If you get anything.

Answer (score -1):

Done.
First did this
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=591#c77

*but* now I was getting a bad request error `"invalid request uri"`. So I then discovered in another google thread that the uri for the v3.0 apis was no longer `http://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/<resource-id>` but `http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/<resource-id>/contents`

Hacked my copy of gdata to replace `folders` with `default` and append `/contents` and voilà, now it worked for pdfs and all the other supported stuff.

Haven't solved the pptx issue, though...